# have I shot myself in the foot... that is the question!

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

Hey guys I think I've just royally shot myself in the foot. I have a website where users have their own profile and can post on their walls but I'm getting to the point where I want to implement that friends can post on my wall and I can post on my friends wall.

This is what my site looks like so far:

[image]

My database design is like so:

[image]

And here is a code snippet of how I achieve posting on walls:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=******;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "')", cn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
    }
}
```

Now my problem is how on earth do I get friends posts on my wall AHHHHH... runs in fear!!!

Have I shot myself in the foot?

Also this is how I generate my content on the page:

```
private void PopulateWallPosts(string userId)
    {

        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT idWallPosting, wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN User u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE wp.UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
            {
                //("SELECT wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    test1.Controls.Clear();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        div.Attributes["class"] = "test";


                        div.ID = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                        string id = Convert.ToString(div.ID);
                        //store the div id as a string
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
                        img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                        div.Controls.Add(img);
                        div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;" + "{0}", reader.GetString(1))));
                        div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "confirm_delete(" + id + ");");
                        // send the div id to javascript
                        div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                        test1.Controls.Add(div);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "')"` <-- That is a MAJOR SQL Injection problem right there. Stop whatever you are doing right now and read up on parameterized queries: http://forums.asp.net/t/1208609.aspx  -- Also, please do NOT post your password, even if it's localhost.

Comment: its ok its juts a vmware and yes I know about the sqlinjection thanks for the input

Comment: Why do you think you've shot yourself if the metatarsals?

Comment: Also, if you practice like you play, code like it's for real. Good habits are good habits.

Comment: Holy smoke, Batman, that's quite a problem!

Comment: because i cant insert friends wall postings? atleast thats how it looks, obviously i dont want to display every userids wall comment on my wall and the atm i can only display userid = to mine

Comment: Jared thats true, Cosmin to the Bat Cave!

Comment: This is a matter of [code refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

Comment: My first thought when I saw this was: oooh yet another Facebook clone rising..

Comment: nah just abit to chat the umf of the site is on creating diet plans and workout plans watching your progress and allowing more advanced weekend gym warriors to help you along in your quest to become Batman!

Comment: Nice sense of humor too.

Comment: @Garrith: Is there any particular reason why you don't use any O/RM mapper such as LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework? Makes life much easier, code better to read, and saves you from having any SQL injection bugs.

Comment: Because im hardcore! Nah jk lol tbh I really dont know about them, havent tryed them, im still a novice. This is my first project!

Comment: @Steven - Do you have any suggestions for some good mappers that are free? I have Visio at work but I'm wondering if there are some good free options.

Comment: update the problem still remains in mycode answers below didnt solve it

Comment: @Jared: I see you use a MySQL database. NHibernate is a free open source O/RM tool that supports MySQL. NHibernate however, is not easy to learn. If you use Visual Studio 2010, go for Entity Framework (I believe EF is even included in the Express editions). You can download a MySQL provider for Entity Framework from the MySQL site (here: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net). A few quick start video's will show you how to use Entity Framework. Invest a few hours of your time in learning the EF basics, and you never go back to those awful low level database queries ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your WallPosting table needs another userId, representing who sent it ( The first one being whose wall it is).

Then just handle those two userids in your insertion code: Who sent it, who's it for.

**EDIT**
Here's what a sample select would look like:

```
SELECT wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath 
FROM WallPosting wp 
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = wp.PostedByUserID 
INNER JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID 
WHERE wp.UserID=" + userId + " 
ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC
```

I would also keep a record of at least what date/time the post was made and order by/display that.

Comment: actually this doesnt solve it shit... if you notice in my code I set the div id to the userid and all the pictures and wallpostings are related via that id aswell i dont think there is a way to do via my method

Comment: theres no way in my method to pull out two sets of records if the wall post is by me then i can if the wallpost is by another user then i can but i cant retrieve two sets of records

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. Are you talking about the sql for getting wall posts?

Comment: its the code aswell as the sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526062/sql-syntax-problem-and-or-code-probelm

Comment: @Garrith: Software design is an iterative process.  If your current design doesn't support your requirements then you need to modify or replace it.  Robert's answer gives you a very sensible basis for implementing your new feature, and it shouldn't be a huge step to integrate it into your current design, even if it requires some rework of your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you need to add another table called 'Walls', bind those to a User, and then have Wallpostings have a 'Wall Id', then just retrieve all WallPostings that have the ID equal to the ID of the user's wall..

Comment: You only need a separate 'Walls' table if there's more than 1 wall per user... otherwise, you can just add a 'OwnerID' field to the 'WallPostings' table

Comment: exactly what i was thinking means a refurbish to all mysql syntax for wall postings lucky its only two statements!

Comment: but its how I refer friendID in my friends table to my wallpostings that going to give me a headache